# Maven needed when generating Google App Engine backend in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, maven, android-studio

## AndroidDev

So I'm trying to add a Google App Engine backend to my app.  I'm using Android Studio 0.3.0.  When I try to "Generate App Engine Backend" I get the following error:

Could not find a valid installation of maven. Perhaps you have not installed Maven or have not setup your Maven paths

I'm a little at a lost because I thought that Maven was installed by default with AS?  Does anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. You have to set the enviroment variable M2_HOME to the path to your maven installation. For me that was "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\apache-maven-3.1.1". I have maven seperatly from AS but I think this would also work if you point M2_HOME towards the AS installation of maven. Additionally you can try to add the bin folder of you maven installation to the Path enviroment variable. In my case that was "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin".

There seems to be a bug in the newest version of AS. You have to explicitly set the path with the enviroment variables otherwise it will not work. Setting the path in Settings -> Maven (after checking override) does not work.
Here's the link to the issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61783

Comment: Can you elaborate some more please. I went to Settings -> Path Variables -> + And created the M2_HOME variable with a path set to my maven directory and I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

## Linux Solution

You have to install maven & Google Cloud messaging for Android.

From terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

Then inside Android Studio:

1. Tools > Android > SDK Manager
2. Scroll down to Extras
3. Check Google Cloud Messaging for Android
4. Install

Answer (score 0):

maven is not shipped with AS - you have to install it

Comment: I'd like more explanations on that since AS does have Maven support. Also when I look in the AS plugins the Maven jars are there.

Comment: why do you think it is an assumption? was just very short describing the root cause - the accepted answer was just more verbose ...

Comment: Maven is shipped with the AS package... you are just not looking for it. If  you go to your AS isntallation, it will be under plugins -> maven (version number). So, you made an assumption that it was not there, and it is. IntelliJ has shipped with Maven for a long while now.

Comment: It is shipped with the maven plugin, but not maven - this is a difference and the problem that @I_Artist had

Answer (score 0):

Dec 26 2013  Maven 3.1.1 does not successfully complete the code generation, switch to Maven 3.0.5  for success !  This is for Android Studio 0.3.2    make sure you edit your PATH information as explained in Maven install.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently on Studio 0.4.2

After lots of Googling I was still unable to resolve this. I have tried all suggested solutions the best answer I found was this

This is posted Jan 15 2014

"Yes, sorry this is a bug, however we're moving to a Gradle based build so in the future Maven wont be the build system that App Engine templates are realized (sic) with."

[Google Issues for Android Studio](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61783)

---

update on Mar 26th 2014 This has been moved to Gradle from Maven