# mobile backend starter import to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, android-studio

This is my first post in StackOverflow.

I am building an android app using Android Studio. This app requires some cloud backend to sync user data across devices. After some research, I came across the Mobile Backend Starter from google which provides a fully deployed app engine backend and a client android application.

The problem is that every video/tutorial out there is using Eclipse to open this client application. When you try to import it to Android Studio, you get an Assertion:Null error.

Another step I tried is that, I opened it in Eclipse, followed google documentation to set

And then tried to import to Android Studio. This time I got an error that the "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Can someone help me out with this? Is it also possible to use the "Generate Mobile Backend" option in android studio? But wouldnt this mean that we cannot leverage the client libraries provided in Mobile Backend Starter?

**Edit (to add more details to the question):** 
If I use the "Tools > Google Cloud Tools > Generate App Engine Backend" method, will I be able to get all the boiler plate code in the Mobile Backend android client?

Also, I tried today to Generate App Engine Backend and point to my existing Mobile Backend Starter app engine project. But this did not bring in end point connections for mobilebackend api. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is an option in Android Studio also for Generating App Engine Backend.

```
Tools > Google Cloud Tools > Generate App Engine Backend
```

Here is a nice tutorial on Android Blog for the same

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/06/adding-backend-to-your-app-in-android.html

But  look in to this post before doing this as Google App Engine Back-end still uses maven so you need to install that before using it.

[Maven needed when generating Google App Engine backend in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504120/maven-needed-when-generating-google-app-engine-backend-in-android-studio)

Comment: Uodate: Maven is no longer needed it is all done in Gradle now

Comment: Thanks @RyanHeitner for update but sorry I did not noticed that, can you please let me know after which version of Android Studio it is done so I can update my answer with proper reference.

Comment: Here is the source I used: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61783

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for those that come to this now the easiest way to get started is with this unofficial build for android studio. Why couldn't google do this themselves?

https://github.com/thagikura/mobile-backend-starter-android-client-with-AndroidStudio