# Maven error in Android Studio while generating Google App Engine backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

When ever i try to generate a backend for my project in Android Studio, i get this error

`Could not find a valid installation of maven. Perhaps you have not installed Maven or have not setup your Maven paths`

I know this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871698/googleappengine-backend-generation-with-android-studio-fails-due-to-maven-instal) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504120/maven-needed-when-generating-google-app-engine-backend-in-android-studio) but no working answer was ever given.Am hoping Maybe someone has solved this?

Comment: Both the questions you linked have accepted answers.

Comment: Yes,but the authors say it doesn't solve their problems.